# Object ( without ) movement during Unity3D animation state-machine

Tags: unity-game-engine, state-machine

I am trying to learn how to implement animation state machines & I seem to be going wrong somewhere.

When I try and make an enemy object follow and trigger an 'attack' when in proximity.

Triggering an attack works, however the enemy object refuses to follow or even move for that matter.

I'm not sure if I have made a mistake in the code below or there is somewhere else, like the animations themselves.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class enemyRun : StateMachineBehaviour
{

    public float speed = 2.5f;
    public float attackRange = 3f;

    Transform player;
    Rigidbody rb;
    //Boss boss;

    // OnStateEnter is called when a transition starts and the state machine starts to evaluate this state
    override public void OnStateEnter(Animator animator, AnimatorStateInfo stateInfo, int layerIndex)
    {
        player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform;
        rb = animator.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        //boss = animator.GetComponent<enemy>();

    }

    // OnStateUpdate is called on each Update frame between OnStateEnter and OnStateExit callbacks
    override public void OnStateUpdate(Animator animator, AnimatorStateInfo stateInfo, int layerIndex)
    {
        //boss.LookAtPlayer();

        Vector3 target = new Vector3(player.position.x, player.position.y, player.position.z);
        Vector3 newPos = Vector3.MoveTowards(rb.position, target, speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        rb.MovePosition(newPos);
    
        if (Vector3.Distance(player.position, rb.position) <= attackRange)
        {
            animator.SetTrigger("attack");
        }
    }

    // OnStateExit is called when a transition ends and the state machine finishes evaluating this state
    override public void OnStateExit(Animator animator, AnimatorStateInfo stateInfo, int layerIndex)
    {
        animator.ResetTrigger("attack");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a really nice AI solution for objects to follow - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mx9M0ieR1M0

Struggling to get animations to work along side but hopefully it's possible